Error calling non-existent method due to different Jandex versions (JBoss vs SmallRye)
I'm facing an issue in my Java application where Hibernate (version 6.4.1.Final) attempts to call a method org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.indexWithSummary(java.io.InputStream) which is missing. The error details are as follows:
Error location:
org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassDescriptor(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65)
Error message:
The following method did not exist: 'org.jboss.jandex.ClassSummary org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.indexWithSummary(java.io.InputStream)'
Context:

org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler is loaded from hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar.
The method indexWithSummary is expected in org.jboss.jandex.Indexer, which is available in Jandex versions used by:

Keycloak (JBoss Jandex 2.4.4.Final)
Hibernate (SmallRye Jandex 3.1.2)



The issue arises due to conflicting versions of Jandex used by Keycloak and Hibernate. Keycloak uses the JBoss version while Hibernate uses the SmallRye version.
How can I resolve this compatibility issue where both Keycloak and Hibernate can function correctly with their respective versions of Jandex?
I tried forcing the usage of the JBoss Jandex version (3.1.2) in my application, which resolved the issue. However, I am uncertain about the potential impact on Keycloak, which relies on its own version of Jandex (2.4.4.Final).
